# Insert into a junction table at the same time as another table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So I have three tables that relate to each other: "Card", "Icon", and a junction table "CardIcons". CardIcons has two columns, "CardID" and "IconID", that link to the two tables. I've created a table type to enable me to do bulk inserts into the Card table, which has an extra column not in the Card table labeled "IconIDs", which is just comma separated ints. What I want to do is create a stored procedure that takes that table type as a parameter, and for each row in that table parameter, I want to insert 1 row into the Card table, get the resulting identity (CardID) from that insert, and insert into the junction table for each int in the "IconIDs" column with that new CardID. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**SCOPE_IDENTITY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) function and wrap your INSERT's into a transaction.  Here's the basic idea (excluding the code to query the TVP and parse the Icon ID's):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @CardID INT
[loop through TVP]
    INSERT INTO Cards (CardID) VALUES ([value])
    SET @CardID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    [loop through icon id's]
        INSERT INTO Icon (CardID, IconID) VALUES (@CardID, [icon id value])
    [end loop]
[end loop]

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```